# How to migrate/copy postgresql tables to oracle using python?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, postgresql

I am using DataFrame to read data from each postgres table and using to_sql() method to insert data into the oracle. The problem I am facing is that It gets stuck after copying a few records to oracle. Jupyter Notebook gets busy but does nothing.

```
def duplicateData(conn, conn2, session):
    
    query1 = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'"

    all_tables = session.execute(query1)
    
    count = 0

    for index,tables in enumerate(all_tables):
        
        count += 1
        
        # getting rid of comma and parathesis
        for i, table in enumerate(tables):

            print("\n"+table+" - NO: "+str(count)+"\n")
            
            query2 = "SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + table + "'"

            columns = session.execute(query2)
            cols = []

            for col in columns:
                cols.append(col[0])

            query3 = "SELECT * FROM " + table

            df = pd.read_sql(query3, conn)

            alias = (table[:30] + '') if len(table) > 30 else table

            df.to_sql(alias, conn2, index=False, schema="PMS")

            print("\nDONE\n")
```

Comment: Using a [foreign data wrapper](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw) would probably be much more efficient

Comment: try to use `executemany` rather than `execute` as being more performant.